# Run exe file from Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I run exe file from Mozilla Filrefox?

I tried this but it not working.

```
 var  oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
 var comandtoRun = "C:\\Buziol Games\\Mario Forever\\Mario Forever.exe";
 oShell.ShellExecute(comandtoRun,"","","open","1");
```

Comment: are you sure the path to file is right? You have spaces in it - this always makes problems :)

Comment: You can't use ActiveXObject in Firefox, it's an IE-only technology and has been removed completely in Edge.

Comment: if you have a website that needs to access an exe file, it is generally done by introducing a client app that runs a localhost application

Answer (score 3):

You can't run any system command from a web page. This was only possible with Internet Explorer under certain conditions, but fortunately it's not something you can do with modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your path isn't right. It could be produced by whitheSpaces.

You can solve it by quoting folder names wich contains whitespaces, like this.

```
 var  oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
 var comandtoRun = "C:\\'Buziol Games'\\'Mario Forever'\\'Mario Forever.exe'";
 oShell.ShellExecute(comandtoRun,"","","open","1");
```

If ActiveXObject not works on firefox, you can use `window.open` function.

```
window.open('file:///C:"Buziol Games"/"Mario Forever"/"Mario Forever.exe"');
```

Comment: But now ActiveX not supported in Mozilla Firefox. How can I use  NPAPI in my javascript code to run local exe file.

Comment: Have you tried `window.open('file:///C:"Buziol Games"/"Mario Forever"/"Mario Forever.exe"');`?